# How can I execute the mt.exe in a PowerShell command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, visual-studio, vagrant

I need to run the mt.exe (part of visual studio express) to embed an application manifest into another executable. Usually the mt.exe is called from a Visual Studio command promtp. The procedure is described [here](http://math.nist.gov/oommf/software-patchsets/patch_on_Windows7.html).

I need to trigger this command from a PowerShell command prompt, because I want to do this during a vagrant provisioning. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just use the full path to `mt.exe` if it is not recognised by PowerShell.

Comment: when you're in the correct location: `.\mt -manifest patch.exe.manifest -outputresource:patch.exe;1`

Answer (score 0):

You can import the environment variables from Visual Studio's batch script using the `Invoke-CmdScript` function from this article:

[Take Charge of Environment Variables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell)

The function's definition is as follows:

```
# Invokes a Cmd.exe shell script and updates the environment.
function Invoke-CmdScript {
  param(
    [String] $scriptName
  )
  $cmdLine = """$scriptName"" $args & set"
  & $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe /c $cmdLine |
  Select-String '^([^=]*)=(.*)$' | ForEach-Object {
    $varName = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    $varValue = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    Set-Item Env:$varName $varValue
  }
}
```

Put this function in your PowerShell profile and you can use it to run the Visual Studio script that sets the needed environment variables.

The article also contains `Get-Environment` and `Restore-Environment` functions if you want to implement scope for the environment variables the Visual Studio script sets.